# PaddedForm - DigitBlock only respected for non-padding

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation, output-formatting, padding

I'm trying to pad some binary and hexadecimal numbers using `PaddedForm`, and also to separate the digits into blocks of 4. For example, I'd like a number like `17651` to be printed in binary as `0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0100 1111 0011`, perhaps.

I tried the following (output included):

```
PaddedForm[BaseForm[17651, 2], 32, DigitBlock -> 4, 
 NumberSeparator -> " ", NumberPadding -> "0"]

0000000000000000000000100 0100 1111 0011
```

I also tried the following:

```
PaddedForm[BaseForm[17651, 2], 32, DigitBlock -> 4, 
 NumberSeparator -> " ", NumberPadding -> "0000 "]

0000 0000 0000 0000 00100 0100 1111 0011
```

Neither one properly handles both the padding on the left side *and* the `DigitBlock` separator.

I can make a complicated function like the below, but is there a way to get `PaddedForm` to play nice with the `DigitBlock` option?

```
PaddedBlockForm[int_, base_ : 10, minDigits_ : 1, block_ : 9999] := 
 Module[{extraDigits, preRiffle, digits},
  
  preRiffle = IntegerString[int, base];
  digits = Max[minDigits, StringLength@preRiffle];
  extraDigits = Mod[block - Mod[digits, block], block];
  
  ToUpperCase@StringDrop[
    StringRiffle@
     StringPartition[
      StringPadLeft[
       preRiffle,
       digits + extraDigits,
       "0"
       ],
      block
      ],
    extraDigits
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what the problem is with your second output. Does `StringInsert[IntegerString[17651, 2, 32], " ", 1 + 4*Range[8]]`  produce the desired output?